# SQL Server update column with value from another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two SQL tables:

**User**:

- `UserId` (nvarchar)
- `Tags` (nvarchar)

**Profile**:

- `UserId` (nvarchar)
- `Tags` (nvarchar)

Example:

**User** table:

```
UserId      Tags
----------------------------------
1           tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4
2           tag1,tag2
3           tag1
4           tag2,tag3,tag4
```

after the Profile table tags should be

**Profile** table:

```
UserId      Tags
-------------------------------------
1           ["tag1","tag2","tag3","tag4"]
2           ["tag1","tag2"]
3           ["tag1"]
4           ["tag2","tag3","tag4"]
```

Currently the user tags are stored in `User` table in the `Tags` column like this, separated by comma: `tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4`. There can be also one single tag listed: `tag1` (no comma present).

I need to "move/copy" those tags in the Profile table Tags column in the following format (string array): `["tag1","tag2","tag3","tag4"]`

So basically in my update statement bellow, second line: `SET Profile.Tags = UA.TAGS`, `UA.TAGS` value should be converted into an array of strings.

```
UPDATE Profile
SET Profile.Tags = UA.TAGS (UA.TAGS value should be an array) 
FROM Profile UP INNER JOIN User UA ON UP.UserId = UA.UserId
```

Any ideas how I can achieve that?

Comment: You should **never ever** store multiple values in a single column - this violates even the **first normal form** of database design. Since you're using a **relational database** - use the **relational** capabilities of it - define a separate table `Tags` for the tags, and a "link" table between either `User` and `Tags`, or `Profile` and `Tags` ...

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE Profile
SET Profile.Tags = '["'+ REPLACE(UA.TAGS,',','","') + '"]'
FROM Profile UP
INNER JOIN User UA
on UP.UserId = UA.UserId
```